# Any way to navigate in a `snake_case_name` string or variable in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

We have `CamelHumps` config in PhpStorm that allow us to use `CTRL` + `left/right arrows` to navigate in a string or variable name like `myVariableName`.

Is there any way to do it for `snake_case_name` strings/variables?

PhpStorm 2017.2.4
JRE: 1.8.0 amd64 OpenJDK 64-Bit
Linux Deepin 15.4.1

Comment: That option (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys --> Use "CamelHumps" words`) works fine with `$case_snake_example` variable names when using `Ctrl+Right/Left` (Windows 10; PhpStorm 2017.2.4). Please try with all custom (non-bundled by default) plugins disabled.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you but it does not work, at least in the Linux version. I will update my question with more information.

Comment: Not a Linux user .. so do not know about OS-specific nuances. But in general: 1) try with all custom plugins disabled 2) Assign another shortcut to those actions (in Keymap; just to see if it's shortcut-related) 3) backup and delete IDE settings and try from scratch (to see if it has any relation; if not -- easily restore them back from backup)

Comment: Also make sure you are talking about the Editor -> General -> **Smart Keys** -> Use "CamelHumps" words setting and not Editor -> General -> Honor "CamelHumps" words setting... as the latter is for double-click.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have got the solution here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207073835-Where-to-set-word-boundaries-for-Ctrl-Arrow. It is the exact problem that @AndreKR has pointed. My bad! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "CamelHumps" option works for snake-case, too.

Note that there are two settings:

**Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Use "CamelHumps" words**
This is for CTRL+left/right. When it's on, the cursor stops at underscores, when it's off, the cursor jumps whole words only.

**Editor -> General -> Honor "CamelHumps" words when selecting on double click**
This is for double click. When *both this setting and the other one* are on, double click selects parts of words, when *either setting* is off, double click selects whole words only.

Both settings always work for camel-case and snake-case alike, they can not be configured separately. Kebab-case identifiers are always treated as multiple words.

Comment: You are completely right! There are **TWO** CamelHumps configs. Only the second one was active but I activated the first one right now and it works fine. Thank you so much!